# Multiple Submit Form Without Reload

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, reload

I was just wondering if its possible to have a loop of submit forms and then submit from any of these submit forms without refreshing/reloading the entire page.

The reason why I wanna know is because, I am currently working on a website and what I wanna do is for users to be able to press like if they like a picture/message (like a tweet on twitter och an image on instagram) but as of right now, when you press the like button, it refreshes the entire page if I do a simple @using (html.beginform("","")) but if I use jquery, then it only works on the last form (the one at the top)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit-buttons").on('click', function () {
        var id = $('#submit-buttons').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Profile/Like",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("body").html(partialViewResult);
            window.location.href = "/Profile/Index";
        });
    });
});

<button id="submit-buttons" name="id" value="@item.Id" type="submit"></button>
```

## submit-buttons is the like buttons, and what it does is, it takes the value (an id) and passes it to a controller and then inserts it to a database. but there are several of these buttons but only 1 works (the one that was looped last). what have I done wrong? :/

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: If there are "several of these buttons" they cannot have the same id (#submit-buttons)

Comment: As @tocqueville said, don't use an id, but rather select by a class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding your question, but I think that using a `$(this)` selector and `type=submit` would help it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit-buttons").on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Profile/Like",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("body").html(partialViewResult);
            window.location.href = "/Profile/Index";
        });
    });
});

<button id="submit-buttons" name="id" value="@item.Id" type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class for the buttons as the id's must be unique

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit-buttons").on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Profile/Like",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("body").html(partialViewResult);
            window.location.href = "/Profile/Index";
        });
    });
});

<button id="submit-button1" class="submit-buttons" name="id" value="@item.Id" type="submit"></button>
```